# Javascript Dates Not making any sense

Tags: javascript

How does this happen?

```
var d = new Date(2014, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0);   
assert(d.getTime()/1000 == 1388534400);     // somehow, this results in assert(1388466000 == 1388534400)
```

Why wouldn't d be Wed, Jan 1st, 2014 00:00:00 GMT, rather than Tue, 31 Dec 2013 05:00:00 GMT

Comment: For 2014-01-01T00:00:00Z use `new Date(Date.UTC(2014,0,1,0,0,0))`. To see the result as GMT/UTC, use [*toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43).

Comment: Thanks RobG, I ended up using your code to get what I wanted done...

Answer (score 6):

Day of month is numbered from 1, not 0.  Day 0 of a month is the last day of the previous month.

Also note that the API your using is going to construct a date in the local time zone. Even if you construct a date for 1 Jan 2014, it will only look like midnight GMT on that date if your local time zone is GMT.

Comment: Very well.  Thanks.  I added a follow up question which again doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @JayPrime2012 if you have a new question, ask a new question or discuss in these comments - changing your question makes the answers unreadable or obsolete. I rolled back the edit.

Comment: @JayPrime2012 it's the time zone thing - you have to explicitly ask for UTC (GMT) date instances if that's what you want.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes The questions are so related they belong in the same question IMO

Comment: @JayPrime2012 that's beside the point - by changing the question you change the context of the answers, making them appear incomplete or offtopic. This is not a forum but a QA site: if you have a new Q - make a new Q.

Comment: [There's policy on that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-follow-up-questions).

Answer (score 3):

`Date` is localized and follows the timezone of your local computer. Apparently you're in a GMT+5 timezone, and as the other answer points out the day off is explained by the 1-based offset of days.

Comment: I agree - it's the combination of both answers.

Comment: Mine explained the +5, the other the -24 hehe. After an edit both were complete.